# Layer cannot be enabled in GeoServer after restarting computer?

Tags: geoserver

I use PostGIS database, mapserver is GeoServer. Every time I create a workspace to upload layers into GeoServer, I can see the layers be enabled. I can see them in "Layer preview". When I restart my computer, the layers disappear.  I checked in "Layers" of "Data", the layers all were not enabled, I had to upload again. I don't understand what is happening! I installed GeoServer as a service, and the webserver as Apache.

How can I figure out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure PostGIS starts before GeoServer or the latter will disable datastores for which the corresponding DB Connection is disabled.